# Creating suspended background jobs

Tags: bash, sh, background-process, jobs

Using Bash, how can I launch background jobs in the suspended/stopped state?

I have to execute a hundred or so memory-intensive, time-consuming processes. Running them sequentially would take a long time:

```
for i in inputs-list; do
  memory-hog $i
done
```

Whereas running them all concurrently would kill my machine:

```
for i in inputs-list; do
  memory-hog $i &
done
```

I would like my processes to start as background, suspended jobs; then I would use `bg` to resume some of them, while monitoring the memory consumption.

Comment: maybe `man xargs` and search for the `-P` (# of processes) might help you. In any case you'll drive yourself crazy with this, either borrow some more computers, or look for tools like `GNU parrallel` . Good luck!

Comment: Use **GNU Parallel** to control how many run at a time and to schedule according to memory pressure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start each process in the background then send `SIGSTOP`:

```
for i in inputs-list; do
  memory-hog $i &
  kill -SIGSTOP $!
done
```